# jquery form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a jquery fancyzoom box. In that box ,I have a contact form which sends an email on submission. But I am not able to call form submit function due to fancyzoom.
Code is like :

("req_quote.php")

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancyzoom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#popup1_link').fancyZoom({width:610});
       $("#submit").css('cursor', 'pointer');

       $('.reqfrm').submit( function(){
          alert("hell");
       });
     });
     </script>
     <body>
         <form class="reqfrm" id="frm">
            <input type="text" name="name" />
             <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
         </form>
     </body>
   </html>
```

Above file is included in "index.php" which contains the actual link to open the form in fancyzoom box.

(index.php)

< a href="#popup1" id="popup1_link">< div class="blink">Request a Quote< /a>"

If I remove `$('#popup1_link').fancyZoom({width:610});` then i get alert on submission otherwise it goes on form action directly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any JavaScript errors with the fancyZoom call in? Are you including the script file you need to use it? It's hard to say without seeing some more data, or a jsbin / jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The form is submitted in the fancybox js file.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Raul, you need to provide more info for us to help out. You could try any of these things:

- See if you can reproduce this issue within a simple html file, that doesn't have any of the extra stuff that your current page may have. If the issue still persists, put it into jsFiddle and post the link here.
- If you haven't already, install the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) addon for Firefox, and use it's console to check for any JS errors.
- Have a look at the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7GRcL) that I've created. Is this similar to what you are doing? Mine works wihtout any issues.